# TypeError: e is not a function at Object.<anonymous> in BotFramework-webchat@4.8.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, web-chat

I'm trying to customize the BotFramework webchat using node.

I am getting TypeError: e is not a function at Object. (custom-webchat-4.8.0.js:32) only in 4.8.0 version and the same code is working with 4.6.0 version.

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Here am attaching HTML file, package.json and ts files for reference

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "custom-webchat",
    "version": "4.8.0",
    "scripts": {
      "build": "rimraf dist && webpack",
      "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json --project . --test src/**/*.ts",
      "deploy": "aws s3 sync dist s3://www.acai-hub.com/js --acl public-read"
    },
    "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://bitbucket.iaas-at-mit.de/scm/bot/bebop-webchat.git"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
        "adaptivecards": "1.2.5",
        "botframework-directlinejs": "^0.11.6",
        "botframework-directlinespeech-sdk": "4.8.0",
        "botframework-webchat-component": "4.8.0",
        "botframework-webchat-core": "4.8.0",
        "core-js": "^3.5.0",
        "markdown-it": "^10.0.0",
        "markdown-it-for-inline": "^0.1.1",
        "memoize-one": "^5.1.1",
        "microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk": "1.6.0",
        "microsoft-speech-browser-sdk": "^0.0.12",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "sanitize-html": "^1.20.0",
        "url-search-params-polyfill": "^7.0.0",
        "web-speech-cognitive-services": "^6.0.0",
        "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0",
        "botframework-webchat": "^4.8.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
        "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.8.3",
        "@types/node": "^12.12.18",
        "@types/react": "16.8.25",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.12.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.12.0",
        "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^5.2.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.4.3",
        "concurrently": "^5.0.2",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.17.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.3.0",
        "isomorphic-react": "4.8.0",
        "isomorphic-react-dom": "4.8.0",
        "prettier": "^1.19.1",
        "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
        "typescript": "^3.7.3",
        "webpack": "^4.41.3",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
        "webpack-stats-plugin": "^0.3.0",
        "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
        "ts-loader": "^6.0.4",
        "tslint": "^5.18.0"
      },
      "peerDependencies": {
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
      }
  }
```

index.ts:

```
import { WebChat, WebChatOptions } from "./custom-webchat";

let webChat: WebChat;

export function renderWebChat(options: WebChatOptions, element: HTMLElement) {
  webChat = new WebChat(options);
  webChat.renderWebChat(element);
}

window["WebChat"] = {
  ...window["WebChat"],
  renderWebChat
};
```

custom-webchat.ts:

```
import * as BotframeworkWebChat from "botframework-webchat";

export interface WebChatOptions {
  token: string;
}

export class WebChat {
  private directline: any;
  constructor({ token}: WebChatOptions) {
    this.directline = BotframeworkWebChat.createDirectLine({ token });
  }

  renderWebChat(element: HTMLElement) {    
    BotframeworkWebChat.renderWebChat(
      {
        directLine: this.directline,        
        botAvatarInitials: 'WC',
        userAvatarInitials: 'WW'
      },
      element
    );
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="ar">
<head th:inline="text">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body th:inline="text">
    <div class="chatBot" id="bot" role="main"></div>    
    <script src="file:///D:/bebop-webchat/dist/custom-webchat-4.8.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        WebChat.renderWebChat(
            {
               token: 'R-yE15Nt-hI.18_ofkIDC1mBY7GbDABIpFC8K4wjF3989JQLAEUJ2nU'
            },
            document.getElementById("bot")
        );      
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

After opening the HTML file in the browser widget is rendering like below:
[image]

After typing hi in the chat its throwing error like below in console:
[image]
[image]

I followed this https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md link for dependencies.

Please let me know if am missing any dependency.

Note: I am facing this issue only with botframework-webchat@4.8.0

Comment: Actually we have an open issue in web chat(NPM)
Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/3046
As per the issue description and followed workaround like below:
npm install globalize@1.4.2 and tested its working as expected

Answer (score 0):

After following the workaround solution which is mentioned in https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/3046 my problem got solved.

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

there is issue in **botframework-webchat 4.8.0** version so you can fix install botframework-webchat@4.7.1 and make sure package.lock file should have same version 4.7.1.